# The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved

Tags: android

im getting error in my android project The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved and even i import library from properties .
which i downloaded from https://github.com/koush/android-support-v7-appcompat.
and added in project from properties but still getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the appropriate dependency to your module `gradle.build` file as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
}
```

Make sure to synchronize your `build.gradle` file (Right click on file `--> Synchronize 'build.gradle'`) and Clean your project (`Build --> Clean Project`) after the change.