# Why the import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be resolved in my project

Tags: android, eclipse, widget, toolbar

I've  trying create an app which is need Toolbar. I've already add "appcompat_v7.jar" to my project which I've got no result.

I've already review some links below and they couldn't help so.

[The Import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved)

[The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908439/the-import-android-support-v7-app-cannot-be-resolved)

[The Import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved)

Here is my "AndroidManifect":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tabex"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also image from Eclipse:

[image]

[image]

As you can see other import from v7 works but the Toolbar not. I've really appropriate your help.

Comment: are you able to import import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: may be u r using old JAR since ActionBaractivity is depracated

Comment: Try to extend MainActivity to AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Zero : I can't add import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity. For old version you've said I've upload my SDK Manager and don't think its old.

Comment: try to decompile that  support jar and check whether it contains Toolbar or not

Comment: I dono howto this, but do you know where i could find one of them which you sure have this Toolbar, link,address...

Comment: try to change your  targetsdkversion to 23 which is the latest one

Comment: I've tried that and unfortunatly not worked. Is it possible for you to create one empty project with eclipse and add this lib to it and sent it my email( sadegh69@gmail.com ).Thanks alot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your SDK Manager screenshot, you are using an old version of the Support Library. The Toolbar widget did not get introduced until v21, you are using v20. Upgrade to latest.

Comment: Thanks. I've upgraded to 23.0.1 and hopefully it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've Upgrade my Android Support Library to Latest version which is **23.0.1** and It's work hundred percent.